# How to create a contacts page properly?

Tags: php, sql, friend

I want to do a contacts page.   Here is my table structure:

```
Accounts Table: 

1) id
2) User_id
3) Full_name
4) Username
5) Email
6) Password

Contacts Table: 

1) My_id (This is the user who added friend_id)
2) Contact_id (this is the contact who was added by my_id)
3) Status
```

My query looks something like this:

```
$sid = ID of user who is viewing;

$sql = "SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT contacts.contact_id, 
accounts.full_name FROM contacts INNER JOIN accounts
on contacts.contact_id = accounts.user_id WHERE 
contacts.my_id = '$sid' OR contacts.contact_id = '$sid'";
```

The problem is that it doesn't work the right way.  I end up seeing my name in the query (meaning when i login i see my name in the contacts instead of contacts name).

How to fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query ought to suffice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contacts.contact_id, accounts.full_name
FROM contacts, accounts
WHERE (contacts.my_id = '$sid' AND contacts.contact_id = accounts.user_id)
OR (contacts.contact_id = '$sid' AND contacts.my_id = accounts.user_id)
```

Comment: Yes, I have never successfully selected from two different tables simply by putting them in a CSV list.  (`FROM contacts, accounts`)

Comment: You are mistaken, or have not used proper statements then. You can find this syntax in the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html and I have used it in a great many deployed projects on MySQL.

Comment: You're right! :O I just tried it. I guess, the only difference is they are not _joined_ into one record each.

Comment: Using your code gives me this error: Error: Table 'database.accounts_accounts_accounts' doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks your code worked but what do i do if i want to add a 3rd table?

Comment: Happy to help! It will depend on the structure of table 3 and how it will link together (on what column value of table 3, and what column value of table 1 or 2) but you can certainly join in a 3rd table.

Comment: Ok, i tried a few things but failed.  Not sure how.  I have a third table with note_id, my_id (person posting), note_name.  Now using the contacts table i want to see if the person viewing is a friend, if not then it shouldn't work...

Comment: OK i sort of figured it out but now i want to add another AND condition in the () but that seems to be failing... not sure why..

Comment: Hey i figured out how to make it but one quesiton.  i want to add a ORDER BY date_time DESC.  Upon doing so it says column is ambigous.  I have that same column in all the rows, so how can i sort them by date using the above solution? Thanks @SetSailMedia in advance

Comment: No problem! You will need to specify a table to pick that column from (so `ORDER BY contacts.date_time DESC` or `accounts.date_time` or from table 3.

Comment: You can run SQL such as this to step through each row: `<?php $rs = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM [...]'); while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs ) ) { var_dump( $row); [... more code here...] } ?>`

Answer (score 2):

The `STRAIGHT_JOIN` keyword should not be necessary here.  To get the contact information, use a second `JOIN` to the `contacts` table which relates it back to the accounts.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT c.contact_id,
  cn.full_name
FROM 
  accounts a
  /* first join connects the adding user's id to records in contacts */
  INNER JOIN contacts c ON a.user_id = c.My_id
  /* second join connects contact list user ids back to names in accounts */
  INNER JOIN accounts cn ON cn.user_id = c.Contact_id
WHERE a.User_id = '$sid'
```

Comment: `contacts.full_name` does not appear to exist (at least not in the table the OP provided)

Comment: The join does appear to be necessary in order to get `accounts.Full_name`.  But other than that, a solid answer! +1

Comment: @SetSailMedia Fixed - needs a second join

Comment: Hey using yours i got this error: Error: Table 'database.accounts_accounts' doesn't exist

Comment: @ariel Are you using the current version exactly as it currently is? There's nothing in there resembling `accounts_accounts`

Comment: Hey yes i double checked but i am getting the same error again.

Comment: @ariel ??? What database client or API are you using that is prepending table names like that? Makes no sense.

Comment: Shouldn't cn.full_name be a.full_name since full name is only in accounts table? I might be wrong since i dont know that much but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Thats the first time i have seen such an error myself. I am not using any API, using phpmyadmin.

Comment: @ariel No, the accounts table is joined twice intentionally, the second aliased as `cn`. I have no idea how phpmyadmin is configured, but it is definitely doing something odd if you're pasting in my query and it's spitting out all that other junk like `database.accounts_accounts`

Comment: Yeah that is weird.  i also checked my logs and nothing that relates to this.

Comment: Ok upon further testing it seemed like i had a conflicting table name.  Once that was fixed i got this error:  Error: Unknown column 'contacts.contact_id' in 'field list'.  ANd i know for a fact it does exist because i am using it in another page.

Comment: @ariel my fault, should be using the alias `c.contact_id`